# Using the For loop on selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

This is Monique from Boston. 
I have created a VBA Script that works good on one row. Now I want to make it happen on all selected rows.

E.g.

```
Sub AutoButton_click()
   Dim a As Range, b As Range

   Set a = Selection

   For Each b In a.Rows
      Dim SellPrice As Double, CostPrice As Double
      CostPrice = Range("C" & a).Value    
      SellPrice = CostPrice + 20    
      Range("D" & a).Value = SellPrice
   Next
End Sub
```

But I keep getting type mis match errors.
What am I doing wrong? 
Please help me.

Thank you so much. x.

Answer (score 1):

More directly

```
Sub AutoButton_click()
   Dim rng1 As Range
   For Each rng1 In Selection.Cells
       Cells(rng1.Row, "D").Value = Cells(rng1.Row, "c") + 20
   Next
End Sub
```

If speed is important do this with a variant array instead

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
For Each b In a.Rows
    'your code here
Next
```

to this:

```
For Each b In a
    'your code here
Next
```

The reason you're getting a type mismatch is because `a.Rows` isn't proper syntax; the compiler doesn't know what you're referring to. Check out [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195745%28v=office.15%29.aspx) for more info on the `Range.Rows` property.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ARich's answer, change lines

```
CostPrice = Range("C" & a).Value
Range("D" & a).Value = SellPrice
```

to

```
CostPrice = Range("C" & b.Row).Value
Range("D" & b.Row).Value = SellPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line `Set a = Selection` and add the below line

```
Set a = Selection.Cells
```

Hope it helps